# 10 inch tablet with 149 PPI is showing as 160 dpi in program

Tags: android, tablet, dpi

Samsung galaxy 10 inch tablet spec is saying that its display density is 149 PPI.

But when I printed dpi using display metrics its showing  as 160 dpi.

how to know the exact dpi of an devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPI and DPI is two different things. The important thing to know about when developing Android applications is the DPI.

It can be found like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int dpi = dm.densityDpi;
```

Android works with general classes of DPI:

- ldpi = 120
- mdpi = 160
- hdpi = 240
- xhdpi = 320

Take a look here for more information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @cantOna actually I want to design graphics for android. so did I want to use PPI or DPI values ?

Comment: Use dpi for designing graphics for android.

Comment: U mean as 160 dpi for both 10'inch and 7 inch'.

Comment: Yes, Android devices select their graphics based on which folder they are in, e.g. drawable-mdpi/ or drawable-hdpi/. So if both 7-inch and 10-inch has 160 dpi they will use the graphics from -mpdi, hence they use the same size of graphics.

Comment: @EricNordvik But you still able to differentiate between tab 7 inch & 10 inch
`7 inch > large-mdpi`
&
`10 inch>xlarge-mdpi`
> If you want make different design for tab 7 inch & 10 inch.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Cant0na answer, which is totally correct, in this [great post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105051985738280261832/posts/AzwMc3pSDUU) Dianne Hackborn (Google engineer) explains exactly how the dpi works. I think the reading of it is a must for every Android dev. Among other things, she says:

> So Android defines a few major buckets of density values that devices
>   can used, called ldpi (approx 120dpi), mdpi (160 dpi), hdpi (240 dpi),
>   and xhdpi (320 dpi). Manufacturers can select the density that is
>   appropriate for their device, as long as it results in a screen that
>   (after scaling for density) is within the minimum allowed screen size
>   of the platform.

Comment: actually I want to design graphics for android. so did I want to use PPI or DPI values ?

Comment: You asked the exact same question earlier, and got an answer for it. Use that answer.